# function call with function pointer in c++

Tags: c++, function-pointers

Here's the code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
typedef struct ptrs
{
    int (*addptr)(int a, int b);
}mems;

int add(int a, int b)
{
    int result = a+b;
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    mems ptrtest;
    ptrtest.addptr = &add;
    int c = (*ptrtest.addptr)(3,4);
    //int c = ptrtest.addptr(3,4);
    cout << c << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

if I replace the code **int c = (*ptrtest.addptr)(3,4);** with it's next line(annotated now), the result will be the same, why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, `int c = (*ptrtest.addptr)(3,4);` is the base case. However, in C++ (and in C as well), if you use the call (`()`) operator on a function pointer, it will do the "dereferencing" automatically. Just like when assigned to a variable of function pointer type, the name of a function decays into a function pointer, i. e.

```
int (*fptr)() = some_func;
```

is just as valid as

```
int (*fptr)() = &some_func;
```

**albeit** the type of `func` is `int ()(void)`.

Comment: Pedantically, `ptrtest.addrptr(3,4)` is the "base case"; C++ defines the function-call operator to act on function pointers, and it acts on functions via the standard function-to-pointer conversion.

Comment: @MikeSeymour That's interesting (as far as I know, in C, it works conversely, but I may need to read up on that). Do you have a section of the Standard to share?

Comment: Actually, I think I misread C++11 5.2.2/1 slightly. It's actually defined for both functions and pointers, and functions *aren't* converted to pointers. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Functions and function pointers can be used interchangeably, presumably for convenience.  In particular, section 5.2.2 of the C++11 standard specifies that a function call can occur using a function or a pointer to a function.

Answer (score 0):

C++ will automatically cast a function name to a function pointer (and vise versa) if doing so will create correct syntax.

Comment: This question is about the reverse of that.